# How do I get these numbers "counting" up every 5 seconds ?? (ObjC; Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, addition

I want that my ball gets faster in my game. in pos you can choose the speed of the ball. But I want the ball getting faster every 5th second. pos = CGPointMake(5.0,4.0);  after 5 seconds 5.0 should turn into 6.0 and 4.0 into 5.0.

I have a Timer which is named MainInt. MainInt is a counter and it counts the time how long you're playing without loosing.

There's also a label which shows the timer.
(IBOutlet UILabel *seconds; .h)

.m

---

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[lastTime setHidden:YES];


[super viewDidLoad];
// X Speed Y Speed
pos = CGPointMake(5.0,4.0); // <- these numbers (add 1 each every 5 sec.)
Speedy = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0  target:self selector:@selector(doThis) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

/*




-(void)doThis {



if(MainInt % 5 == MainInt)     //True every 5th second
{

    pos = CGPointMake();
}

}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one thing, `MainInt % 5 == MainInt` is *false* after 5 seconds for the rest of eternity. 1-4 are the only values of `MainInt` that would ever make that true. Consider reviewing how the modulo operator works. Even if you change this to `MainInt % 5 == 0`, which is correct, you still have to ask yourself why you're checking for anything there regarding an external asynchronous time value. All this will do is, if the timer is not in synch, force it to not do anything every single time it is called because you already set it's delay between calls to 5 seconds. If you want everything to synch up nicely, you should probably have one main NSTimer or CADisplayLink in charge of a game loop where you can call methods that need to update your game's state every frame.

If you really want to do it this way with separate timers for everything and try to keep them in synch with your main time value, then here you go.

```
//replace timer line with this one
Speedy = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1  target:self selector:@selector(doThis) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//replace body of "doThis" with the following
if(MainInt % 5 == 0) //True every 5th second
{
    pos = CGPointMake(pos.x + 1, pos.y + 1);
}
```

Also, you should follow some sort of naming convention and try to name things more clearly. If `pos` is the speed of the ball, shouldn't it be named `velocity` instead of position? What is `Speedy`, an instance variable? If so, why is it uppercase? Plus, Speedy is one of the most unclear name's I've ever heard; it's not a pet, it's a variable. Same thing for `MainInt`. In general, reserve uppercase names for class names and use camel case for instance variables, methods and functions. It'll make your code clearer. :)

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm 16 years old and my English is not perfect cause I'm from Germany :D I try to keep em in my mind giving em names i can remember easier :D but I'll try to get clearer in my definitions next time, thank you :)

Comment: @EndritÇallaki No need to apologize. I didn't mean to sound condescending or anything. Your English is actually pretty good! If you code alone, the best thing to do is to make sure your variables have names that reminds *you* of what they are used for. Just keep in mind that if anyone else needs to read your code (such as in a team environment) it's good if they can understand your intent quickly as well. The naming conventions for uppercase/lowercase letters are the most important, in my opinion, so that you can differentiate between different things quickly.